# Data Binding No such method and field error in multi-module project

Tags: android-databinding

Am trying to use listener binding && binding adapters in a multi-module project.Module using data-binding is not the entry point of the project.
i.e Module A is the entry of the application and does not use data binding while module B which is a child uses data-binding.
Done the following : all modules have data-binding enabled
Note: I can use data-binding to reference views and set data on views in(Module B) but when it comes to setting binding-adapter/listener binding project crashes.

```
composeBinding = FragmentMessageComposeBinding.inflate(inflater, container,
        false).apply {
        viewModel = composeViewModel
        lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    }
```

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field viewModel of type I in class  android/BR; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.android.BR' appears in /data/app/com.android-L6pvy0tcl4JFvccGwrsAGw==/base.apk!classes2.dex)